# getter doesn't work when converted from textfield to property in Struts 2

Tags: properties, nullpointerexception, struts2, textfield

I had a textfield in Struts 2 defined as

```
<s:textfield key="fName" label="First Name" readonly="true" />
```

and the getters were working fine, but since it was supposed to be only a display only field, I changed it to

```
<div> <br /> First Name: <s:property value="fName" /></div>
```

and now the getter gets a NullPointerException.

Is there a way to circumvent this error? thanks

getter in Person.java:

```
public String getFName() {
 return fName;
}
```

stacktrace:

```
test.model.Person.getFName(Person.java:43)
test.service.PersonDAO.update(PersonDAO.java:182)
test.action.UpdatePersonInfo.execute(UpdatePersonInfo.java:46)
```

Comment: @Aleksandr M getter and relevant stacktrace added.  Like I said, there's no NPE if I replace property by textfield

Comment: You mean you get NPE after submitting the form? Use hidden field. Also read this https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html#Struts2.3to2.5migration-Fieldnames.

Comment: @user1005585 but the value is empty correct (if using the textfield)? If that is the case... then use something like <s:if test="fName != null"><s:property value="fName" /></s:if><s:else>user is not logged in[provide login link]</s:else>, although that is a bit of a hack, I would move the check to the getter and return an empty string if it is null there.

Comment: @Quaternion The value is not empty.  There's a value always and it works with the textfield element, but not with property.  I am on struts 2.3.15.  Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Just for a sanity test, could you change `return fName;` to `return "Bob";`? Also are you using ModelDriven? Something is pretty odd.

Comment: @Quaternion  Thanks, now this is interesting.  I hardcoded "Bob" and there's no NPE.  So does this reinforce the idea that the fName value is not being transmitted automatically from the jsp to the valuestack automatically when the 'property' tag is being used?

Comment: @Quaternion and yes, I am using ModelDriven

Comment: @user1005585 Generally it's a good idea to show the actions and jsp's involved. I've set up so many struts2 apps that it takes no time at all to make a demo... it is best to strip out everything to make the issue as clear as possible (Pojo only has getfName and not a dozen other things...) if you do this, you will get excellent help. Although between you and me, about half the time (at least) you'll solve your own problem. There are too many things that it could be. Obviously fName _is_ null, no doubt about it.

Comment: @Quaternion  Thanks, and that's what I intend to do when I get a chance.  As of now, I'm getting away with it using a textfield and it's not functionally affecting my work.  But hopefully, sometime next week, I'm going to create a HelloWorld and strip it to its barebones and see what happens.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful choosing class variable name, in you case fName. With new version of struts 2 which uses newer version of OGNL, some of the getter/setter are not working properly. This is because newer OGNL follows Java bean specification. So your getter would be

```
 public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this.  And it still throws an NPE on form submit with the property element, but not with the textfield element.

Comment: Since you are using struts 2.3.15 your getter method is correct. Did you debug your action class ?

Comment: Yes, I did with both the textfield and property elements.  When used with the textfield, the getter returns a value.  But with property, it's like the value isn't getting populated automatically and therefore an NPE.

Comment: @user1005585 try this <s:property value="%{fName}">

Comment: thanks again.  Unfortunately, %{fName} causes an NPE too.  I think I'm going to use textfield/readonly for now, and then when I get a chance, I am going to upgrade to 2.5.x and hope for the better!

Comment: @user1005585 Read my comment below your question.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks, but wouldn't be using a hidden field be a hack.  When I use an editfield, it works the way Struts2 docs say: I declare a class field with setters and getters and use the same name in the jsp, and things work.  Shouldn't it work the same way for other form fields as well?

Comment: @user1005585 For other **form** fields, exactly. The `<s:property>` is not a form field. Check generated HTML.

Comment: @AleksandrM OK Thank you very much.  I'll check my HTML and hack around if that's my only way out.

Comment: @user1005585 It is not a hack. It is how forms work.